# session.max.allowed liferay property is not working as expected

Tags: session, connection, liferay

I have set this session.max.allowed 1000.
Even if only 10 users are accessing site still I am getting error of max session exceeded.
I have also enabled session invalidation filter on.so that new session which are going be more then 1000 it will be invalidated.
Then why I m getting this session exceeded error.

Comment: I assume that you mean the `SessionMaxAllowedFilter`. You should check if the property is effective (in the control panel). Depending on the location of your property definition it can happen that another definition takes precedence and overrides your definition.

Comment: Are you working with an EE trial version? This is the default behaviour of trials. Contact sales for trying more sessions concurrently.

Comment: @Olaf KockThanks for the reply but solution is not to increase the connection,Its about only ten user are using this site then why 1000 sessions used??!

Comment: @Tobias: I have checked multiple times in code as well but no luck.Yes you are right about sessionMaxAllowedFilter.

Comment: So which version are you using then?

Comment: Did you buy Liferay EE or are you using the trial? The trial is limited like you described. If you're an EE customer, just open a ticket with Liferay support - that's what it's there for

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in the comments it looks like you're using the Trial version of Liferay EE. If this is the case: Note that the trial comes with exactly that limitation. Contact Liferay sales for an EE subscription and you'll get the full version.

If you are already paid subscriber, you should just open a ticket with Liferay support. That's what they're there for and what you pay for in EE if it doesn't work.